# what is the meaning of "if False: from typing import Type"?

Tags: python, types

While going over [pytest src code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/daff9066c0c4ed1108a391fe3efcf6df5ab905ca/src/_pytest/_code/code.py#L25) I found that peculiar statement, can someone please explain?

```
if False:  # TYPE_CHECKING
    from typing import Type
```

I'm actually looking over [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) currently, and I think that this may somehow be connected to annotations, but not sure how. Is it possible that someone would annotate `False` in a way that it would evaluate to `True`?

After a quick look in the [typing](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py) src, I found that:

```
# Constant that's True when type checking, but False here.
TYPE_CHECKING = False
```

So from what I gather so far, @chepner is right. This statement is evaluated to `True` when running a type check, and then the actual import is probably needed. Though that still looks really weird to my eyes (`#if DBG` in C was way clearer)

Comment: Since `False` isn't true, this does nothing.

Comment: @scott Hunter that's exactly what I'm wondering about. Is this a dead code? it appears on many of pytest's src code files, so I think it would be weird...

Comment: It is dead code; as to *why* it is there, you'd have to speak to an author who included it.

Comment: I was thinking maybe this checks that `False` was not set to another value in Python2, but then `typing` did not exist in Python2

Comment: Yes, this is a way to remove or pass over rather than commenting out a section of code or removing it entirely. Commonly called an `if DEBUG`. I assume `typing.type` is deprecated and removed as of now. It's entirely up to the author, some would rather just comment it out!

Comment: This is also not intended to be used anywhere in the code since there is not reference to `Type` anywhere.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Weirdly enough, this was never removed, it was directly added like this as per commit [this commit](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/commit/55a570e5135cc8e08f242794b2b7a38677d81838#diff-eb0ddbc8c0fe892bd0b8cce2282bdc1aR23)

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I'm not sure... If that was true, what is the meaning of the "type checking" comment?

Comment: `TYPE_CHECKING` itself is an attribute of the `typing` module, set to `False` in ordinary code but `True` (I presume) when a type checker is processing the code.

Comment: Looking at the blame of the file, here is what I've found 
https://github.com/asottile/flake8-typing-imports#rationale

Comment: @kasptom Not sure what to understand from that. If the module is unstable, how would `if False` save me? (unless it is a constant that somehow evaluates to `True` while type checking)

Comment: @ClsForCookies, not sure if it is related https://github.com/python/typing/issues/230 but looks similar

Comment: I guess it may be possible that at run time the compiler or a typechecker is evaluating it differently but I would assume that they are guarding this import. Perhaps it's unstable in most versions and would require a custom import in script. In `C#` we would use an `#if DEBUG` to hide code on release.

Answer (score 2):

```
if False: 
    ...
```

was an old way of writing what's now (since Python 3.5.2) done with

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING: 
    ...
```

[`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) is

> A special constant that is assumed to be `True` by 3rd party static type
>   checkers. It is `False` at runtime.